# Multiples router url

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, router, angular-router

**¿Cómo ocultar multiples vistas con router url?**

```
  <ion-header *ngIf="!isHeader()">

  isHeader() {
    return this.router.url === '/view';
  }
```

Comment: En caso la directiva ngIf es true o false asi o otra condicion que tambien sea true o false, asi puedes añadir las rutas y depende si quieres ver la o no todo depende de true o false

Comment: @tomasz-vizaint quiero que no se muestren varias view/pages tipo: '/view00' && '/view01' && '/view02'.. ¿Sabes un ej claro?, Gracias.

Comment: y que resultado esperas?

Comment: @tomasz-vizaint evitar que se vea el header en varias views concretas. ¿Tienes un ejemplo de multiples rutas?

Comment: No tengo, lo unico se me ocurre es *ngIf="miview == esteconcretoview else otroview". Agui te dejo un link sobre ngIf talvez encuetras respuesta a tu pregunta. https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf